# How to use HttpURLConnection over SOCKS proxy on Android

Tags: android, proxy, socks

Well, I have been trying to use SOCKS proxy on android. Too much I am struggled and I failed to use it correctly.

Basically I do want to get a content of a page over a SOCKS proxy using `HttpURLConnection` (is a must).

The code I am using is this:

```
    String proxyHost = "192.168.2.2";
    int proxyPort = 1999;
    InetSocketAddress proxyAddr = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, proxyAddr);

    URL request = new URL("http://requestb.in/sgjga5sg");

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) request.openConnection(proxy);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(36000);
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(44000);

    InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    for (int x = is.read(); x >= 0; x = is.read()) {
        System.out.print((char) x);
    }
    System.out.println();
```

I do get `SocketTimeOutException`, here is the stack trace:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socksReadReply(PlainSocketImpl.java:440)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socksRequestConnection(PlainSocketImpl.java:340)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socksConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:326)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:181)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:887)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:174)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:276)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
at com.guness.testsocks.MainActivity.doTheThing(MainActivity.java:81)
```

Some curious things:

- The proxy points to my SSH tunnel (apparently tested on other devices using firefox socks proxy feature).
- When I change `Proxy.Type` to `HTTP` and choose an appropriate HttpProxy from internet it works, but I need socks.
- Don't mind `System.out.print` and the loop, it is there for test purpose.
- Test device is a C6603 model and Android version 5.1.1

---

Edit:
It seems that SOCKS proxy does not work with `HttpURLConnection` on android. Some references:
This [thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/guardian-dev%40lists.mayfirst.org/msg01006.html) and this [thread](http://guardian-dev.mayfirst.narkive.com/aBGKAwSG/netcipher-and-httpurlconnection) claims so. I want to be sure if there is a way without using 3rd party libraries.

Comment: You are using okhttp. That's a 3rd party library. I don't know what version of the library you are using, but okhttp just added SOCKS support recently. Have you tried using the version of `HttpURLConnection` that is built into Android?

Comment: Well, I am not using okhttp myself, the native `HttpURLConnection` and `HttpsURLConnection` are used on my code. maybe android internally using okhttp, not sure.

Comment: I don't think so. What device are you testing on?

Comment: Maybe you are suing another 3rd party library that relies on okhttp?

Comment: @DavidWasser: Google has been using OkHttp internally for handling `HttpURLConnection` since around Android 4.4.

Comment: @guness: I have used SOCKS with `HttpURLConnection` successfully, but on `localhost` through Orbot. My guess is that your problem is more specific to your proxy implementation.

Comment: @CommonsWare, so you are saying if I let `proxyHost` be `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` I would be happy huh? Because I was trying to use Orbot and the above code did not accept `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @guness: Sorry, I was working from memory. I use `127.0.0.1`. [This project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Internet/HTTPStacks) represents a proof-of-concept of adding NetCipher/Orbot support to various HTTP stacks (HURL, Apache HttpClient, OkHttp3, Volley). It's large, but a bunch of that code will (slowly) migrate into NetCipher itself. I got SOCKS working with Orbot on everything but OkHttp3, because they don't support SOCKS at all.

Comment: @CommonsWare, so that would be the answer I guess.

Comment: OkHttp3 is not what Android uses for `HttpUrlConnection`. Android uses a fork off of the original OkHttp code, lightly maintained. Again, I have `HttpURLConnection` (a.k.a., HURL) working with Orbot via a SOCKS proxy connected over `127.0.0.1`, using whatever port Orbot wound up choosing (obtained via a NetCipher broadcast).

Comment: @CommonsWare I have applied your HURL implementation and nothing changed as far as I can tell. However when I have switched to `Marshmallow`, all was working like charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem, and solution partially. As stated in my question, the device was `Lollipop(5.1.1)`. When I use an emulator to check `Marshmallow(6.0)` it was working like charm, without any change. Emulator check also fails for `Lollipop`.

So for the future reference:

**Android did not support socks proxy natively`(using HURL)` on devices previous than Marshmellow.**